# ffprobe get bit depth from audio file

Tags: bash, audio, ffprobe

For one of my script I need to read out the bit depth of a wav file.

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=bits_per_sample -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 test.wav
```

there is no output at all -  I use this in the same way for the duration (format=duration) and it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution - the stream needs to be defined:

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=bits_per_raw_sample -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1
```

Comment: `ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=bits_per_sample -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1` seems more consistent

Comment: `ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream` will display all of the possible streams